# Best practice to cache a Marionette View

Tags: javascript, marionette, backbone-views

In the application we are developing, we have a CollectionView whose every ItemView contains a link to the item-details page. Also, every ItemView contains a checkbox, because items can be selected in the CollectionView to perform bulk actions on them.

When switching to the ItemDetails view, we want to **keep the state of the CollectionView**, ideally without having to redraw it (a bit like GMail when switching from inbox to mail and back). Our solution is to **render the two views in two different regions and to hide one when switching from one to the other**.

My perplexity about this solution is that

- Marionette doesn't seem to be meant for this kind of use.
- It is **not very memory-friendly**, since all the DOM elements are never deleted.

Is there any better solution to achieve this goal?
Storing the state somewhere, close the CollectionView and redraw it later is another possible solution, but would it imply a heavy computation overhead? (we are quite scared about redrawing views).

Comment: I've actually created an application similar to this that retrieved a lot of data and had very complex renderings.. personally I just hide the specific regions that don't have the focus. I'm assuming you are using the marionette router and controller, just change the display logic in there.

Answer (score 4):

Marionette allows for showing a view in a region without closing the view that was already rendered. You simply pass in `{preventClose: true}` to the `show()` method of the region. You would still need to maintain a reference to the collection view though so you can later re-show it or close it yourself.

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#showing-a-view

Comment: Good find! This is indeed a nice use case for that option.

Comment: `preventClose` has become [`preventDestroy`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#preventdestroy) by now, mind you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your collection is very large, there's not a problem with just rerendering the collectionView when switching back from a itemDetail view. You do need to store the state of the checkboxes indeed.

However, I don't see what's really wrong with your other approach. It's probably even faster and there's nothing wrong with just hiding one region and showing another. If that works for you, go ahead.

Regarding the memory issue, as long as you're looking at the collection or itemDetail there isn't much to gain by closing either one of the views (especially if your itemDetail views are not very large). Once you move away from that section (thus not looking at the collection or itemDetail view anymore) you could just close the layout that contains these two regions. That'll free up any memory used by these regions.